# Are 0s real or fabricated?

Tags: missing-data, count-data

I am working with data from different brands where I have how much the different brands were bought for a particular day over the period of 1 year. However, I know beforehand that some of the data is not reliable. Specifically, I know that some brands report 0s that are actually missing values for particular days. This is easy to tell for brands that perform very well as I never expect a 0 for any particular day. But things get tricky for low performance brands, as we cannot be sure if the 0s are real or not. Is there a way to, statistically, perform a test that would detect in which situation we are in, that is, where 0s are expected based on the non-0 values vs 0s are probably not real given the non-0 values?

Comment: I would not think in terms of a test. But you could plot your different brands. Fabricated zeros should stick out as isolated, in time or in a distribution. Plausible zeros will occur alongside values of 1, 2, or other low counts. If you have hundreds or thousands of brands and wish to automate any decision procedure, I would look for zeros together with other small counts.

Comment: "This is easy to tell for brands that perform very well as I never expect a 0 for any particular day." It would be tricky to use the good performance as a way to tell whether a zero should be false. I can imagine that the brands that do report a zero for some day, may not have been working that day and effectively add up the number to other days. COVID-19 data has been like this where gaps in the data occur because some days no counting has been done (but still the cases that occured that day have been counted on later days).